# Tidy Up Rails Postgres Production Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, migration

I have moved a column (called score) from one table (contract) to another (weekly_record). I created a new migration for weekly_record. However I removed it from the original table 'by hand', specifically by deleting the column in the original migration.

Everything is fine in development as I have seeded the data back into a new local db via csv files, making sure the 'score' is saved into the new table, and the old column doesn't exist as I deleted all history of it

However in production, all the old records are still intact and I do not want to drop the db and reseed (unless I have to!) and am not sure of the best way to deal with it.

I see the following options:

1. I run a function from the console to copy the 'score' from one table into another. Then remove the old score column via a migration
2. I revert my local migrations back to match the production db and rewrite the migrations properly
3. I drop/create and seed data via updated csv export/import
4. Something else?!

I still am a little scared of playing with production databases. I am so used to wiping and rebuilding the local one constantly

Thanks

Comment: Moving s score to a weekly_record table sounds like something that should happen on a regular basis. I would reset development and write proper and well-tested code for such an operation instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails migration system is designed to work sequentially. If you go back into your previous migrations locally and tamper with them, Rails isn't able to recognize/know the order in which the migrations should be run.

Reverting your migrations to match that of production would be best. Since you have a seed file, you can drop your development DB and rerun the migrations to match production.

After that, generate a new migration that executes the following:

1. Add the new column on weekly record.
2. If any score data needs to be migrated from the contract table to a corresponding weekly record record, write the code to handle that.
3. Drop the old column from contracts.

If you don't like have a long list of migration files in your repo, you can always delete them AFTER ALL ENVIRONMENTS ARE IN SYNC. However, going back through and editing past migrations will often land you in problems like you're facing.